# wxPython empty space when using fit() to size frame

Tags: python, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm trying to set up my GUI so that the frame automatically fits the contents, what it seems to be doing is going the other way and fitting the contents to the frame.

Is this usual and is there anything I can do about it?

Here is my code:

```
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    usernameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.usernameBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(200,35))
    usernameText = wx.StaticText(panel, label="\tUsername")
    usernameSizer.Add(self.usernameBox, 1)
    usernameSizer.Add(usernameText, 1)

    passwordSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.passwordBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(200,35))
    passwordText = wx.StaticText(panel, label="\tPassword")
    passwordSizer.Add(self.passwordBox, 1)
    passwordSizer.Add(passwordText, 1)  

    urlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.urlBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, size=(200,35))
    urlText = wx.StaticText(panel, label='\tFirst chapter URL')
    urlSizer.Add(self.urlBox, 1)
    urlSizer.Add(urlText, 1)

    formatSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.formatBox = wx.ComboBox(panel, value='', choices=self.fileFormat, style=wx.CB_READONLY, name="combo", size=(200,35))
    formatText = wx.StaticText(panel, label="\tFile format")
    formatSizer.Add(self.formatBox, 1)
    formatSizer.Add(formatText, 1)


    downSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    downButton = wx.Button(panel, label='Download', size=(161,50))
    font = wx.Font(20, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    downButton.SetFont(font)
    downSizer.Add(downButton, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)

    mainSizer.Add(usernameSizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)
    mainSizer.Add(passwordSizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)
    mainSizer.Add(urlSizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)
    mainSizer.Add(formatSizer, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, 20)
    mainSizer.Add(downSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.BOTTOM, 20)

    panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    panel.Fit()

    self.Show(True)
```

This bunches all the widgets up at the top which is pretty much what I want, there is a lot of empty space below that however which I don't want.

If I set the proportional value to 1 instead of 0 when adding the sizers to mainSizer it takes up the entire frame, how can I get the frame to contract to the contents?

Comment: Where do you put your panel ? I guess it belongs to self, so what does self inherit from ? It's probably because you give the containing window a size. Could you put the code that's before the one you are showing here>

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to achieve this you need to set the proportion to 0 every time you add something to a`wxSizer`.

Also something that may help is to add the `wx.EXPAND` tag, so it'd be something like that:

`sizer.Add(other_panel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.WATERVER, border_size)`

In theory and having done that, your panel should take the size of its components. Also make sure that you call Fit on the window/dialog that owns the panels.
Sometimes (but rarely) calling the `Layout` function on the sizer helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t work, I still get the same excess space.